# Cómo enviar el idioma cómo un Header en SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring

Estoy intentando envíar el idioma como header , lo llamo Accept-Language , entonces como valor le paso es-ES o en-US por ejemplo , tengo un interceptor creado que funciona correctamente los típicos afterCompletion() , postHandle() y preHandle().

Mi idea es que el interceptor recoja el idioma para hacer la petición y esta la pueda utilizar en el controlador ya que de la forma que tengo el controlador sólo me pilla el mensajes.properties por defecto.

```
 @Controller
    public class LanguageTest {

        @GetMapping(value = "/obtenerIdioma")
        public void obtenerLitaLabels() {
            ResourceBundle bundle1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("mensajes");
            displayValues(bundle1);
        }

        public static void displayValues(ResourceBundle bundle) {
            System.out.println("hello message:" + bundle.getString("default.title"));
        }
    }
```

Los tres metodos de los interceptores son los siguiente.

```
@Component
public class LogInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, Exception arg3)
            throws Exception {
        log.info("Request Completed!");

    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, ModelAndView model)
            throws Exception {

        log.info("Request URI "+request.getRequestURL());
        log.info("Method executed");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws Exception {
        log.info("Before process request");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Quiero hacerlo de esta forma porqué creo que es la mas eficiente , la idea es no tener nada en el controlador.

Por otro lado la opcion B que he probado ha sido de recoger el valor con RequestHeader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se define la lógica del cambio de idioma en un componente de configuración no habría que implementar nada más en todo el proyecto para el cambio de idioma.

```
@Configuration
public class I18nConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

@Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor result = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        result.setParamName("lang");
        return result;
    }



@Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
```

Simplementa llamando a un controlador con el parametro *lang* se efectuaría el cambio de idioma.

También se podría establecer un idioma por defecto añadiendo este metodo al componente

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
    return sessionLocaleResolver;
}
```